# Auto-complete / instant search results box stopped working since changing ASP.NET site from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, https, autocomplete

I have an ASP.NET site within which I have implemented an auto-complete / instant search function for looking up users names. I have a SearchResults.aspx page which essentially renders a JSON list of users matching the 'search term' query string passed to it. The JSON is fetched from Azure Active Directory via an AWS Lambda function.

This is the page load;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }

    List<Users> Results = GetADUsers(Request.QueryString["term"]);

    Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    var output = (from r in Results
                  select new { label = r.Name}).ToList();

    // Then we need to convert it to a JSON string

    JavaScriptSerializer Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string JSON = Serializer.Serialize(output);

    // And finally write the result to the client.

    Response.Write(JSON);
}
```

And this is the function to obtain the users:

```
 List<Users> GetADUsers(string searchParameter)
        {
            List<Users> ret = new List<Users>();
            try
            {
                using (var client = new AmazonLambdaClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2))
                {
                    var request = new InvokeRequest
                    {
                        FunctionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lambdaArnPrefix"] + "lambda-wlyw-GetAzureAdUsers",
                        Payload = "\"" + searchParameter + "\"",
                        InvocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse

                    };
                    var response = client.Invoke(request);

                    string result;
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.Payload))
                    {
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    dynamic _userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < _userList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ret.Add(
                            new Users
                            {
                                Name = _userList[i].userName
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ret.Add(new Users() { Name = ex.Message });
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

I then have my main page which has a search box on it, that basically uses the content from the SearchResults.aspx page to populate results based on what is typed into the search box (so almost like using SearchResults.aspx like a web service).

```
    <script>
$(function() {
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ source: "/SearchResults.aspx" });
    });
    </script>
```

The above javascript references this input:

```
                                    <div class="ui-widget">
                                        <input id="tags" runat="server"/>
                                    </div>
```

And uses the autocomplete javascript available here - http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete (which I did not make, I'm just using).

This AWS Lambda function works fine when tested. 
The SearchResults.aspx page works fine when tested in the browser
However, since moving from HTTP to HTTPS, the text box where input is meant to trigger this whole process, has stopped working. I don't understand why. Maybe the HTTP to HTTPS thing is a red herring? But it's the only change I've made? Can anyone think of a reason why this is no longer working?

Comment: I know next to nothing about JavaScript but I did try to use Firebug JS debugger? And one thing I could note is that the awesomeplete.js script doesn't appear in the list of loaded scripts when I'm on the .aspx page that contains the search box? It has other *.js scripts that are a part of the bootstrap framework. I have no idea if that's meaningful or not.

Comment: I did fix this error "VoteWho:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.wlyw.cloudy-skies.org/VoteWho' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." by referencing the HTTPS URL instead, the error no longer occurs, but the auto complete still doesn't work?